# Difference between two dates in Python

Tags: python, date

I have two different dates and I want to know the difference in days between them. The format of the date is YYYY-MM-DD.

I have a function that can ADD or SUBTRACT a given number to a date:

```
def addonDays(a, x):
   ret = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",time.localtime(time.mktime(time.strptime(a,"%Y-%m-%d"))+x*3600*24+3600))      
   return ret
```

where A is the date and x the number of days I want to add. And the result is another date.

I need a function where I can give two dates and the result would be an int with date difference in days.

Comment: Note that your addonDays function will fail on DST days.

Comment: You are right. I already modify the function. If you add 3600 (one hour) will work.

Answer (score 453, accepted):

Use `-` to get the difference between two `datetime` objects and take the `days` member.

```
from datetime import datetime

def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

Comment: Great answer. To be clear, the result of `(d2 - d1)` will be a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

Comment: I have this error on the console:
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: I get TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when I try to do .days() on a timedelta object and the documentation makes not mention of it either (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Could you please mention [`total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds), too? I think it is important as it is what I expected to get when I tried `seconds` without reading the docs.

Comment: @MartinThoma It works when I tried `return abs((d2 - d1).seconds)`. :)

Comment: @ThejKiran Make d2 and d1 be apart exactly one day and see if it is what you expect ;-)

Comment: to have datetime of file creation, i use `datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file))`

Comment: Note that a `timedelta` only stores days, seconds, and microseconds. All other periods, e.g. hours, require conversion by hand, and the values may be of type `float` for partial values

Comment: @MartinThoma I was starting to think there was a bug in the library. The limits on the `seconds` attribute should have been a red flag.

Comment: @Christian One thing to mention here is that you can **divide by unit**, e.g.: `(datetime(2020, 1, 1, 12, 0) - datetime(2020, 1, 3, 12, 0)) / timedelta(days=1)` gives `-2.0` and `(datetime(2020, 1, 1, 12, 0) - datetime(2020, 1, 3, 12, 0)) / timedelta(seconds=1)` gives `-172800.0`. That is probably the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: for whom do not want abs for diff.

Answer (score 48):

Another short solution:

```
from datetime import date

def diff_dates(date1, date2):
    return abs(date2-date1).days

def main():
    d1 = date(2013,1,1)
    d2 = date(2013,9,13)
    result1 = diff_dates(d2, d1)
    print '{} days between {} and {}'.format(result1, d1, d2)
    print ("Happy programmer's day!")

main()
```

Comment: Isn't the `if` in the `diff_dates` function completely unnecessary? By the definition of the absolute value, `abs(date1-date2)` will always be equal to `abs(date2-date1)`.

Comment: At least with Python3.5 the print statement should look like this:
print ('{} days between {} and {}'.format(result1, d1, d2))

Answer (score 10):

You can use the ***third-party library*** [`dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/), which is an extension for the built-in `datetime`.

Parsing dates with the [`parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) module is very straightforward:

```
from dateutil import parser

date1 = parser.parse('2019-08-01')
date2 = parser.parse('2019-08-20')

diff = date2 - date1

print(diff)
print(diff.days)
```

---

<sup>Answer based on the one from [this deleted duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615842/6045800)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

I tried the code posted by larsmans above but, there are a couple of problems:

1) The code as is will throw the error as mentioned by mauguerra
2) If you change the code to the following:

```
...
    d1 = d1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = d2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

This will convert your datetime objects to strings but, two things

1) Trying to do d2 - d1 will fail as you cannot use the minus operator on strings and
2) If you read the first line of the above answer it stated, you want to use the - operator on two datetime objects but, you just converted them to strings

What I found is that you literally only need the following:

```
import datetime

end_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days=8)
difference_in_days = abs((end_date - start_date).days)

print difference_in_days
```

Comment: My code uses `datetime.strptime` to convert strings to `datetime` objects. Since the OP stated that "The format of the date is YYYY-MM-DD", I assumed the dates were represented as strings. If they're not, there's obviously no need for a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\Data Exploration.csv')
data.head(5)
first=data['1st Gift']
last=data['Last Gift']
maxi=data['Largest Gift']
l_1=np.mean(first)-3*np.std(first)
u_1=np.mean(first)+3*np.std(first)


m=np.abs(data['1st Gift']-np.mean(data['1st Gift']))>3*np.std(data['1st Gift'])
pd.value_counts(m)
l=first[m]
data.loc[:,'1st Gift'][m==True]=np.mean(data['1st Gift'])+3*np.std(data['1st Gift'])
data['1st Gift'].head()




m=np.abs(data['Last Gift']-np.mean(data['Last Gift']))>3*np.std(data['Last Gift'])
pd.value_counts(m)
l=last[m]
data.loc[:,'Last Gift'][m==True]=np.mean(data['Last Gift'])+3*np.std(data['Last Gift'])
data['Last Gift'].head()
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried a couple of codes, but end up using something as simple as (in Python 3):

```
from datetime import datetime
df['difference_in_datetime'] = abs(df['end_datetime'] - df['start_datetime'])
```

If your **start_datetime** and **end_datetime** columns are in `datetime64[ns]` format, **datetime** understands it and return the difference in days + timestamp, which is in `timedelta64[ns]` format.

If you want to see only the difference in **days**, you can separate only the **date** portion of the **start_datetime** and **end_datetime** by using (also works for the **time** portion):

```
df['start_date'] = df['start_datetime'].dt.date
df['end_date'] = df['end_datetime'].dt.date
```

And then run:

```
df['difference_in_days'] = abs(df['end_date'] - df['start_date'])
```

Answer (score -5):

pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01').shape[0]

Comment: Please, correct the answer someway to get the reputation for downvote back.

Comment: Suggest something without "pandas"