# Datetime in python

Tags: python-2.7

how to set format in date time in python.

```
import time

from datetime import datetime
s1=datetime.now()
print s1
time.sleep(2)
s2=datetime.now()
print s2

FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
print tdelta
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [Python format timedelta to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: Have you read the manual? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: they not available format for this datetime.

Comment: output shows like:2014-12-31 17:33:59.692952
2014-12-31 17:34:01.695124
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/trial_projects/check.py", line 14, in <module>
    tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
TypeError: must be string, not datetime.datetime

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: 59.692952 wht this mean in seconds? how to set format for this seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you really should consider reading Python's [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html).  I don't think that you have a formatting problem.  I think that you're misusing the method.  See below.

You don't actually need the `datetime.strptime(s2, FMT)` method, b/c it's job is to return a time object.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3096984/2058922).  Yet the `datetime.now()` returns an object.  [See the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).

Since you're working with two time objects, you can simply subtract one from the other to determine their delta.

```
timediff = s2 - s1
print timediff
```

note that (awesomely) Python transforms your `datetime.datetime` objects into a `datetime.timedelta` object.  see below.

```
s1=datetime.now()
time.sleep(7)
s2=datetime.now()

print type(s1), type(s2)
timediff = s2 - s1
print timediff
print type(timediff)
```

outputs:

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'> <type 'datetime.datetime'>
0:00:07
<type 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

So yeah, Python is awesome; and reading the docs can be fun!