# Finding Date difference in list of dates [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming the following dataset has sorted list of dates:

```
dates=pd.DataFrame(data={'client':['1','2'],
                         'date':[['2012-3-10','2012-3-11','2012-3-12','2012-3-13','2012-3-14'],
                                 ['2012-3-12','2012-3-13','2012-3-16','2012-3-23']]})
```

[image: sample dataset]

I want to find the average date difference in terms of days
So, For eg, for `Client` `'2'`, `Average Timelag` would be `2.75`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with:

```
  client                                               date
0      1  [2012-3-10, 2012-3-11, 2012-3-12, 2012-3-13, 2...
1      2       [2012-3-12, 2012-3-13, 2012-3-16, 2012-3-23]
```

You could

```
dates.groupby('client')['date'].apply(lambda x: [i / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') for i in np.diff([pd.to_datetime(c) for c in x])[0]])
```

to get the `timedelta` in `days`:

```
client
1    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
2         [1.0, 3.0, 7.0]
```

or

```
dates.groupby('client')['date'].apply(lambda x: np.mean([i / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') for i in np.diff([pd.to_datetime(c) for c in x])[0]]))
```

for the `mean`:

```
client
1    1.000000
2    3.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a repeat of:

[Difference between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates)

It looks like you can use the datetime modules to parse the date and/or time strings you're importing into objects which support algebra.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Cheers

Comment: My primary problem is not finding the difference in the dates. It's more about parsing through the list of values