# How to structure the output in timedelta computation?

Tags: python, datetime

I have 2 lists of dicts:

```
hah = [{1:[datetime(2014, 6, 26, 13, 7, 27), datetime(2014, 7, 26, 13, 7,27)]},
                  {2:datetime(2014, 5, 26,13,7,27)}]
dateofstart = [{1:datetime(2013, 6, 26, 13, 7, 27)}, {2:datetime(2013, 6, 
                  26,13,7,27)}]` (just examples).
```

And I need to create a new list of **dicts** that contains the same keys and as a value has a difference between dates from the **hah** and **dateofstart**.

It should look like this:

```
[{1:[365, 334]}, {2:[390]}]
```

When i tried to do it myself i got this code

```
dif = list()
diff = list()
for start in dateofstart:
    for time in hah:
        if start.keys() == time.keys():
            starttime = start.values()
            timeofpay = time.values()
            for payments in timeofpay:
                dif.append(starttime.pop(0) - payments)
            diff.append({str(start.keys()):str(dif)})
```

And it runs with a following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mihailbasmanov/Documents/date.py", line 78, in <module>
    dif.append(starttime.pop(0) - payments)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'list'
```

Edition:

Managed to do it (almost) by myself. Here is resulted code:

```
for start in dateofstartbuyer:
    for time in hah:
        if start.keys() == time.keys():
            starttime = start.values()
            starttimetime = starttime.pop(0)
            timeofpay = time.values()
            for payments in timeofpay:
                if type(payments) == list:
                    for wtf in payments:
                        dif.append(wtf - starttimetime)
                else:
                    dif.append(payments - starttimetime)
            key = str(start.keys())
            diff.append({key[1:2]:str(dif)})
            dif = list()
print(diff)
```

If you have a suggestion how to make this code more productive your welcome to post your suggestions in the comments or in answers.

Comment: Please make sure that the code you posts actually runs. Right now, your second block contains several variables of which we have no idea what they contain.

Comment: I would strongly advise that you simplify the packaging of your data. You have a `list` of individual `dict`s of `list`s. That's a mindful. Try and design from the user side: how would the user use this data?

Comment: @polarise User must be able to see all differences of each user he/she wants to get so I thought that is not a bad idea to create a list where is possible to find a user by his id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: Not a duplicate but the title is misleading. It's more about structuring the result.

Comment: @polarise Yap, you right. And I think I made it with help of the question tripleee sanded.

Comment: This list of `dicts` doesn't makes sense to me. I think these are supposed to be normal dictionaries. Is it? Because, the example that you provided is list of `dict` with just one key in each dictionary. This is not how `dict` works. All the `key` should belong to single `dict` object..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the example that you provided is having typo issues, because:

- `hah` is a `list` of `dict` with just one `key` in each dictionary. Instead it is supposed to be single dictionary. Isn't? Also, for key `2`, value is single `datetime()` object instead of `list`. Isn't it suppossed to be `[datetime]`?

  `hah = [{1:[datetime(2014, 6, 26, 13, 7, 27), datetime(2014, 7, 26, 13, 7,27)]},
         {2:datetime(2014, 5, 26,13,7,27)}]`

Hence, I am assuming `hah` and `dateofstart` as `dict` objects. Below is the code. Let me know in case any of my assumption is incorrect.

```
>>> hah = {1:[datetime(2014, 6, 26, 13, 7, 27), datetime(2014, 7, 26, 13, 7,27)],
...        2:[datetime(2014, 5, 26,13,7,27)]}
>>> dateofstart = {1:datetime(2013, 6, 26, 13, 7, 27), 2:datetime(2013, 6,26,13,7,27)}
>>> dicts = {}
>>> for key, values in hah.items():
...     dicts[key] = [(value - dateofstart[key]).days for value in values]
...
>>> dicts
{1: [365, 395], 2: [334]}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i did it myself long time ago, and then rewrote it so now I even can't find place where I had this trouble so I can't check your solution. Sorry again.