# Calculate difference between 2 dates in python dataframe

Tags: python, datetime

I've looked through python advice and worked out how to calculate the difference between two dates, e.g. [Difference between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates). That works, but ... I'm working with variables in a dataframe. I'm sure I'm following the advice I've read but I'm getting:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Here's the code:

```
df['DAYSDIFF'] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(df['SDATE'],"%d/%m/%Y") - datetime.datetime.strptime(df['QDATE'],"%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Thanks again for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df["SDATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["SDATE"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df["QDATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["QDATE"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

df["DAYSDIFF"] = df["SDATE"] - df["QDATE"]
```

Because `datetime.strptime` does not recognize the pandas Series and is expecting a string.

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat. Though the DAYSDIFF is coming out as "2 days" instead of the number 2. Is that just a formatting thing?

Comment: Yes, this is just a formatting thing. For more information on time series data read [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

Comment: You can divide `DAYSDIFF` by `np.timedelta(1, "D")` to get an int.

Comment: that works too thanks - except it's     np.timedelta64