# Calculating remaining days between 2 dates inputed by user

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two dates where the user is inputing the dates but cannot find how to do it. I currently have this code:

```
from datetime import date

startdate = date(input("When do you intend to start?"))
enddate = date(input("When is your deadline?"))
numstudydays = enddate - startdate
print (numstudydays)
```

Thank you

Comment: You currently have this code ... and, what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an incorrect use of the `datetime` constructor. I revised your solution to handle user input in a simple and manageable way. A basic data validation is performed by the [datetime.strptime factory method](https://docs.python.org/release/3.6.2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) but there could be more (like checking, for example, that the end date always comes after the start date):

```
from datetime import datetime, date

start, end = None, None

while start is None:
    rawinput = input("When do you intend to start? ")

    try:
        # %Y stands for a fully specified year, such as 2017, 1994, etc.
        # %m for the integer representation of a month, e.g. 01, 06, 12
        # and %d for the day of the month
        # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime for more
        start = datetime.strptime(rawinput, "%Y %m %d")
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be \"<year number> <month number> <day number>\"")

while end is None:
    rawinput = input("When is your deadline? ")

    try:
        end = datetime.strptime(rawinput, "%Y %m %d")
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be \"<year number> <month number> <day number>\"")

diff = end - start

print("You have %d days of time" % diff.days)
```

I did more than a couple of tests, and this is what resulted:

```
None@vacuum:~$ python3.6 ./test.py 
When do you intend to start? 2017 01 32
Input must be "<year number> <month number> <day number>"
When do you intend to start? 2017 01 31
When is your deadline? 2017 02 30
Input must be "<year number> <month number> <day number>"
When is your deadline? 2017 02 28
You have 28 days of time
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, `input()` method accepts the input as a string variable. You can then typecast it into an integer using `int()` method. But you cannot typecast an entire tuple. i.e (year, month, day) in your case. 
You can do it by getting all the values one by one.

```
from datetime import date

print("Enter intended start date details: ")
year = int(input('Year: '))
month = int(input('Month: '))
day = int(input('Day: '))
startdate = date(year, month, day)

print("Enter intended enddate details: ")
year = int(input('Year: '))
month = int(input('Month: '))
day = int(input('Day: '))
enddate = date(year, month, day)
numstudydays = enddate - startdate

print (numstudydays)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This answer is not inherently wrong, but it doesn't perform data validation by checking that month days are out of range, for example. The [datetime](https://docs.python.org/release/3.6.2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) module documents more standard and proven ways of achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your biggest issue is how you retrieve the date.
date() function requires three integers, e.g. date(2017,10,10)

When you use input() you get a string:

```
input()  #returns a string
```

You would also need to solve this by splitting the input somehow:

e.g.

```
"2017-10-12".split("-") # returns ["2017","10","12"]
[int(i) for i in "2017-10-12".split("-")] # returns [2017,10,12]
```

That means if you do this, you get a date:

```
date(*[int(i) for i in input("When is your deadline?").split("-")])
```

But what you really want in this case is to use strptime. Strptime() converts a string to a datetime by defining how it looks:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("20171012","%Y%m%d").date() # returns: datetime.date(2017, 10, 12)
```

---

**Example of full script**

```
from datetime import datetime

startdate_str = input("When do you intend to start? e.g.(2017-10-10)")
enddate_str = input("When is your deadline? e.g.(2017-10-11)")

startdate_dt = datetime.strptime(startdate_str,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
enddate_dt = datetime.strptime(enddate_str,"%Y-%m-%d").date()

numstudydays = enddate_dt - startdate_dt

print (numstudydays.days) # prints 1 for example inputs
```

**Recommended links**

The various kind of ways to format a string:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior