# Calculating time delta of users

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have user session ids and the timestamp of the session ids where some event occurs. I want to calculate the time between the first event and the last event. Please see the example below:

```
session_id   timestamp
sess1        2018-11-05 14:28:25.260
sess2        2018-11-04 12:14:59.576
sess2        2018-11-04 11:55:00.584
sess2        2018-11-04 12:16:44.702
sess3        2018-11-04 12:04:37.419
```

I want to calculate the difference between the first and last timestamp of sess2 and likewise all other session_ids like this:

```
session_id   timeSpent
sess1        1
sess2        125 (for example)        
sess3        1
```

How to calculate this?

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python)?

Comment: this is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert column to datetimes if necessary
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

#aggregate min and max
df1 = df.groupby('session_id')['timestamp'].agg(['min','max'])
#subtract to new column
df1['timeSpent'] = df1.pop('max') - df1.pop('min')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  session_id       timeSpent
0      sess1        00:00:00
1      sess2 00:21:44.118000
2      sess3        00:00:00
```

One row solution with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and tuple:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('session_id')['timestamp']
        .agg([('timeSpent', lambda x: x.max() - x.min())])
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
  session_id       timeSpent
0      sess1        00:00:00
1      sess2 00:21:44.118000
2      sess3        00:00:00
```

If need output in seconds convert timedeltas by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df1['timeSpent'] = (df1.pop('max') - df1.pop('min')).dt.total_seconds()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  session_id  timeSpent
0      sess1      0.000
1      sess2   1304.118
2      sess3      0.000
```

One row solution:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('session_id')['timestamp']
        .agg([('timeSpent', lambda x: x.max() - x.min())])
        .assign(timeSpent = lambda x: x['timeSpent'].dt.total_seconds())
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
  session_id  timeSpent
0      sess1      0.000
1      sess2   1304.118
2      sess3      0.000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` in combination with `apply` and substract `max - min`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('session_id').timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min()).reset_index()

df1.rename({'timestamp':'timeSpent'},axis=1,inplace=True)

print(df1)
  session_id       timeSpent
0      sess1        00:00:00
1      sess2 00:21:44.118000
2      sess3        00:00:00
```

In seconds:

```
df1 = df.groupby('session_id').timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min()).reset_index()
df1.rename({'timestamp':'timeSpent'},axis=1,inplace=True)
df1['timeSpent'] = df1['timeSpent'].dt.total_seconds()

print(df1)
  session_id  timeSpent
0      sess1      0.000
1      sess2   1304.118
2      sess3      0.000
```