# fulfilling the condition after subtracting two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm executing a command `print(end_date - start_date)` and I get in console:

```
3 days, 0:00:00
10 days, 0:00:00
11 days, 0:00:00
11 days, 0:00:00
```

etc.

I want to make a condition that

`if all end_data - start_data >= 2` (days)`:`

```
    print('OK')
else:
    print('Error')
```

How can I put 2 days instead of 2 (int number)?

Comment: you could use [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta): `if date1 - date0 >= timedelta(days=2): ...`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta
timedelta(days = 2) # 2 days, 0:00:00 (<class 'datetime.timedelta'>)
```

> Here is nice article how to manipulate date and time in Python :
>   https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime

Comment: Was checking the same code in my console :P Good one.