# Getting error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

```
date_list = [x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') for x in [tframe['Start_Date'].tolist() + timedelta(minutes=30*x) for x in \
                                                    range(0, abs(tframe['End_Date'].tolist() -tframe['Start_Date'].tolist()).days*48)]]
```

Comment: Please try writing this again, this time without trying to cram everything into a single line.

Comment: It probably doesn't even need to be in a list like this anyway and could be handled in Pandas but it's very difficult to follow

Comment: What are you expecting `tframe['End_Date'].tolist() -tframe['Start_Date'].tolist()` to do? You can't subtract lists. Why do you convert them to lists if you want to subtract them?

Answer (score 1):

the issue is here:

```
tframe['End_Date'].tolist() - tframe['Start_Date'].tolist()
```

In python you cannot subtract a list from another.

It seems like you are trying to calculate the time difference between End_Date and Start_Date.

Refer to the following link on how to handle date_difference:

[Difference between two dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python)