# How to convert a date into int, starting from a specifc date? Python

Tags: python, date, integer

I would like to convert a date into int value, but the int should be the difference of the date and another date that I specifed. To be more clear, let assume that I want to convert the date 15/03/2020 in the int difference between it and the base date, that for example is 02/02/2020. In this case I would obtain 41 as result, cause it is the difference in days between the 2 dates. How can I do it in python?

Comment: Already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python

Comment: Yes it does, I will remove this question

Answer (score 1):

You might subtract `datetime.date` from `datetime.date` to get `datetime.timedelta` i.e.

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.date(2020, 3, 15)
d0 = datetime.date(2020, 2, 2)
diff = (d1-d0).days
print(diff)
```

Output:

```
42
```