# Python: Comparing two dates

Tags: python

I would like to know how many days are passed from a `x` ago to today

I wrote this:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1629195530 # A month ago
before = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
daysBefore = before.strftime("%d")

now = datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%d")

print(f"daysBefore {daysBefore} - today {today}")
daysPassed = int(today) - int(daysBefore)
```

But so it seems, `daysBefore` is returning the days of the month, I can't get my head around this :(

Comment: You mean `(now - before).days`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, Thank you... so easy to miss :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact format with date time hour minute accuracy

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1629195530 # A month ago
before = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
now = datetime.now()
print(now - before))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f"daysBefore {daysBefore} - today {today}")
```

The reason this doesn't work is that it gives the day of the month. For example 17th of July and 17th of August will give a difference of zero days.

Therefore the recommend method is as @abdul Niyas P M says, use the whole date.time format to subtract two dates and afterwards extract the days.

Comment: That's why I asked the question, I don't know how!

Comment: Again, credits to @Abdul Niyas P M : `daysPassed= (now - before).days`  will give the days passed.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to this: `strftime("%d")`
You are converting you date to a string and then to an int to make the difference. You can just use the datetime to do this for you:

```
timestamp = 1629195530 # A month ago
before = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
now = datetime.now()

print(f"daysBefore {before} - today {now}")
daysPassed = now - before
print(daysPassed.days)
```