# I can't count days between two dates

Tags: python

I'm trying to count days between two dates but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is the code I am using:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

hoy = date(datetime.today().strftime("%Y,%m,%e")) #current time
otra_fecha = date(2022, 11, 5)
delta = hoy - otra_fecha
print(delta.days)
```

This is the error that is thrown:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: See [Difference between two dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python).

Comment: `hoy` is a string. Leave it as a date

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the TypeError since `datetime.today().strftime("%Y,%m,%e")` returns a str and [datetime.date()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) takes int as arguments.

1. You can use [date.today()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) to get the current local date.

```py
hoy = date.today()
```

2. You can also use the [date()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) method to extract the date from datetime object.

```py
hoy = datetime.today().date()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.date()` on `datetime` object to get back the `date` object:

```
hoy = datetime.today().date() #current time
```