# How can I find the number of days that have elapsed between two dates?

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

I have already created functions to check whether a year is leap year or not `is_leap_year` and another function `ordinal_date` that checks the number of day a date is in a year.
I am now trying to create a function that calculates the number of days that have elapsed between two dates. Unfortunately my function is returning inconsistent wrong number of days.
*Here is my function*

```
def days_elapsed(year1: int, month1: int, day1: int, year2: int, month2: int, day2: int) -> int:
    days_in_month = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if year1 == year2:
        if month1 == month2:
            return day2 - day1
        else:
            ordinal_date1 = ordinal_date(year1, month1, day1)
            ordinal_date2 = ordinal_date(year2, month2, day2)
            return ordinal_date2 - ordinal_date1
    else:
        days_in_year1 = sum(days_in_month[month1:]) - day1
        days_in_year2 = sum(days_in_month[:month2]) + day2 - 1
        years_in_between = sum(366 if is_leap_year(year) else 365 for year in range(year1 + 1, year2))
        total_days = days_in_year1 + days_in_year2 + years_in_between
        return total_days
```

`days_elapsed(1945, 1, 1, 2023, 10, 4)` returns 28,764 days instead of 28,765 days
`days_elapsed(2023, 1, 1, 2023, 12, 31)` correct number of days elapsed (364).
`days_elapsed(2012, 1, 1, 2023, 10, 4)` returns 4292 days instead of 4294 days

Comment: Is your answer found here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python
There's also one here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates

Comment: Can you determine which part of your calculation is in error for these examples (`days_in_year1`, `days_in_year2`, and/or `years_in_between`)?

Comment: Is this just an exercise? Because the simplest solution would be to create two `datetime.date` objects and subtract them.

Comment: It is just an exercise where I have to use my other two functions (is_leap_year and ordinal_date), so I can't use datetime.date here.

Answer (score 0):

> `days_elapsed(2012, 1, 1, 2023, 10, 4)`

The function currently counts the leap years between the two provided years but doesn't consider that one of the years provided could be a leap year.

2012 was a leap year and it is also the first year provided. Your function only considers the leap years in between the two years provided:

`days_in_year1 = sum(days_in_month[month1:]) - day1`

The month < 2 so the `days_in_year1` will be one day less than it should.

---

After you fix that, you will have a consistent error of just one day. This could be fixed by removing the `-1` from the calculation of `days_in_year2`.

> `days_in_year2 = sum(days_in_month[:month2]) + day2 - 1`.

I don't know why you added it, but I believe that it will work if you change it to:

```py
days_in_year2 = sum(days_in_month[:month2]) + day2
```